# Multi-layered permissions in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, permissions, authorization, acl

I'm trying to implement a service which allows users to create "organizations" as subdomains. I want my users to allow inviting people to invite them to their "organization", e.g. orgname.exampleapp.com.

As I have a fair bit of familiarity with Symfony, I'd like to use it to build this project. I've read a fair bit of documentation on roles, groups, voters, etc. but I can't quite piece it together. Therefore my question:

How would I best approach building a permission system in Symfony 2.6+ matching this criteria:

- Users should register on a main page, e.g. `example.com`
- Users should be able to create organizations, which get assigned a subdomain (e.g. `orgname.exampleapp.com`)
- Users should be able to invite people to organizations.
- Users should be able to put people into groups for a specific organization.
- Users should be able to assign permissions to groups for a specific organization.

I have control over the servers I intend to run this on, so I am not opposed to constructs that use an SSO or require provisioning an own virtual machine / cloud server / etc.

Comment: [sonataadminbundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle) will do quite a lot of that for you and is highly configurable (use with FOSUserBundle)

Comment: I took a look at sonata' briefly, but I actually want to understand how you'd do this with Symfony, as in how the parts would plug together. I don't like using components without understanding what they are / should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voters suits your requirements just fine. They're simple and allows to validate complex rules.

In my personal experience, it's about changing mindset from typical ACL approach. Saying that, I recommend you checking [these slides with comparison of ACL and Voters](http://slides.com/marieminasyan/drop-ace-use-role-voters#/), where it's nicely explained.

Comment: Thank you, I wish the Symfony documentation would be as in-depth and explaining concepts in relation to each other like these slides. I will play around with Voters a little more, I'll see if I can make it work easily.

Comment: Best sources are usually presentations/blogs. I wish that too, so I've started working on selection of best Symfony education sources - [Awesome Symfony](https://github.com/Symfonisti/awesome-symfony). You might find it useful.